# Python: Recursion: Output optimal path

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

I do have a (hopefully) small problem with recursive functions in python. I wrote a short sequence alignment algorithm optimizing the alignment of two lists for a given substitution matrix (s) and gap cost (n). The function works fine and returns reasonable alignment scores.

However, I also need the optimal path taken in the end which led to the alignment score. As I am new to recursive programming, I don't see how the path may be assembled and returned by the function.

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
b = ['a','c','d','a','e']
c = ['c','a','b','c','a']

s = {}
for i in ['a','b','c','d','e','f']:
    s[i] = {}
    for j in ['a','b','c','d','e','f']:
        if i == j:
            s[i][j] = 0.0
        else:
            s[i][j] = 1.0


n = 0.5

def f(l1,l2,i,j):
    if i > 0 and j > 0:
        sub = f(l1,l2,i-1,j-1) + s[l1[i]][l2[j]]
        lag1 = f(l1,l2,i,j-1) + n
        lag2 = f(l1,l2,i-1,j) + n
        fval = min(sub,lag1,lag2)
    elif i > 0:
        fval = f(l1,l2,i-1,j) + n
    elif j > 0:
        fval = f(l1,l2,i,j-1) + n
    else:
        fval = s[l1[0]][l2[0]]
        result = []
    return fval

def align(l1,l2):
    score = f(l1,l2,len(l1)-1,len(l2)-1)
    print score

align(a,b)
align(a,c)
align(b,c)
```

Does anyone have an idea how I may return the path? Preferrably, the output is a list containing the (i,j)-tuples for each step in the path.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your code, so I can't provide a thorough answer with code examples, but here's a hacky option: make a global list and append every path decision to that list. When the function call is complete, your global list will contain every step along the path regardless of what stack frame you were in when it was decided. If I could tell where in your code the decision is actually made, I would have given you a proper answer. I don't really understand this algorithm though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list structure that you pass along with the recursion to track the path.  At each step, you add the current piece to your path, append any recursive results, and pass the list back up to your caller.  Here are modifications to your `f` and `align` functions:

```
def f(l1,l2,i,j, path=None):
    path = [] if path is None else path[:]
    path += [(i,j)]
    if i > 0 and j > 0:
        sub, subpath = f(l1,l2,i-1,j-1)
        sub += s[l1[i]][l2[j]]
        lag1, lag1path = f(l1,l2,i,j-1)
        lag1 += n
        lag2, lag2path = f(l1,l2,i-1,j)
        lag2 += n
        fval = min(sub,lag1,lag2)
        if fval == sub:
            path.extend(subpath)
        elif fval == lag1:
            path.extend(lag1path)
        else:
            path.extend(lag2path)
    elif i > 0:
        fval, ipath = f(l1,l2,i-1,j)
        fval += n
        path.extend(ipath)
    elif j > 0:
        fval, jpath = f(l1,l2,i,j-1)
        fval += n
        path.extend(jpath)
    else:
        fval = s[l1[0]][l2[0]]
    return fval, path

def align(l1,l2):
    score, path = f(l1,l2,len(l1)-1,len(l2)-1)
    print '{} : {}'.format(score, path)
```

This produces the following output:

```
1.0 : [(4, 4), (3, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)]
3.0 : [(4, 4), (3, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
3.0 : [(4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 3), (0, 2), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
```

Note that I haven't optimized this to reduce the amount of list copying.  Also, in your first case, if `sub`, `lag1` or `lag2` are equal, it just returns the path of the first one in that order, which seems to be an arbitrary choice if they have equal scores.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much, this is exactly what I have been trying to do for some hours now but I always got all possible paths in the output because I passed it on as an argument in each step. Your solution suits my purpose perfectly.